# Flask+gevent: logging events from within the Process instance not handled

Tags: python, flask, multiprocessing, gevent

I want to implement Server Side Events in my application. I'm using Flask with a gevent backend. I mostly follow the official [snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/116/), with two important distinctions:

1. The function that fires events is spawned as a separate process (an instance of `multiprocessing.Process`), instead of `gevent.spawn`. It sends "inner" event
2. Event firing is done via logging, with `QueueHandler` from `logutils`

Here's a minimal example:

```
from flask import Flask, Response
import time
import logging
from gevent.wsgi import WSGIServer
from gevent.queue import Queue
import multiprocessing as mp
from logutils.queue import QueueHandler

app = Flask(__name__)
logger = logging.getLogger('events')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

@app.route("/publish")
def publish():
    logger = logging.getLogger('events')
    def notify():
        time.sleep(1)
        logger.info('inner')

    logger.info('outer')
    p = mp.Process(target=notify)
    p.start()
    return "OK"

@app.route("/subscribe")
def subscribe():
    def gen():
        logger = logging.getLogger("events")
        q = Queue()
        handler = QueueHandler(q)
        logger.addHandler(handler)

        while True:
            result = q.get().message
            yield result

    return Response(gen(), mimetype="text/event-stream")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = logging.getLogger()
    root.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
    root.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    app.debug = True
    server = WSGIServer(("", 5000), app)
    server.serve_forever()
```

**The problem** is, `StreamHandler` catches both "inner" and "outer" events and logs them to stdout. `QueueHandler`, on the other hand, only pushes the "outer" event to the queue, so it fails to catch the "inner" event, which originates in other process.

Now, if I use `multiprocessing.Queue` instead of `gevent.queue`, the "/subscribe" route blocks. If I use standard werkzeug server (with threading) in conjunction with `multiprocessing.Queue`, the code above works as expected.

What's going on and how to tackle this?